# How to make return type generic in interface?

Tags: java, generics

There are three Java 1.6 interfaces inheriting one from another:

```
interface First<T extends First<T>> {
  T me();
}
interface Second<T extends Second<T>> extends First<T> {
}
interface Third<T extends Third<T>> extends Second<T> {
  void foo();
}
```

Now I'm expecting this one to work, but no:

```
// somewhere later
public void bar(Third t) {
  t.me().foo();
}
```

Compiler says that `t.me()` is of type `Second`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When i try it, the compiler seems to think t.me() is of type first!

Comment: @Tom even worse. Do you know how to make the compile think that `t.me()` is of type `Third`?

Comment: As Beyoncé Knowles put it (paraphrasing slightly), if you wanted to use it, you should have put a type parameter on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public <T extends Third<T>> void bar(Third<T> t) {
    t.me().foo();
}
```

Comment: could you please review my question again, I made a correction at the end. I have no control over `t` instantiation. It's of type `Third` for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't supplied a type parameter in the declaration of t, which makes it a raw type. All reasoning around generics is thus out of play. Because me() is declared as returning a type T in a class parameterised with T extends First, its raw type is First, and that's what the compiler will treat it as being even when it came from a Third.

If you were to supply a parameter to t - of any value! - the compiler would be able to use the rules about generics, and could work out that me() returns a Third. For example, writing some class Foo as Oli suggests would do it, as would binding it to ?.

If you have an instance of Third as a variable of raw type, assign it to a variable of type Third. That is legal, never unchecked, and will get you where i think you need to be.